# Could NOT find OpenCL (missing: OpenCL_LIBRARY)

Tags: cmake, opencl

I'm trying to use OpenCL with CLion (specifically [boost compute](https://github.com/boostorg/compute)), using CMake, on windows 10 with nvidia gpu. It feels like I have tried everything, but I have no idea how CMake works, and I cannot find a basic enough post on the web for me to understand. The official documentation isn't that helpful to a beginner either. I also need to eventually get this running on OS X and some flavour of Linux.

This is the mess I'm in (CmakeLists.txt):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(cpl)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -O2")

set(SOURCE_FILES
        src/planner/main.cpp)

set(BOOST_ROOT C:/boost)
set(BOOSTROOT C:/boost)

include_directories(lib/compute/include)

include_directories($ENV{CUDA_PATH})

# boost
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.60.0 REQUIRED)

# opencl
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH lib/cmake)

find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

LINK_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCL_LIBRARY})

message(STATUS "OpenCL found: ${OPENCL_FOUND}")
message(STATUS "OpenCL includes: ${OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "OpenCL CXX includes: ${OPENCL_HAS_CPP_BINDINGS}")
message(STATUS "OpenCL libraries: ${OPENCL_LIBRARIES}")

#target_link_libraries(cpl OpenCL)
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\drathier\.CLion2016.1\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\drathier\.CLion2016.1\system\cmake\generated\cpl-bfc654e8\bfc654e8\Debug --target all -- -j 8
-- Boost version: 1.60.0
CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Users/drathier/.CLion2016.1/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.5.1/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenCL (missing: OpenCL_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /cygdrive/c/Users/drathier/.CLion2016.1/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.5.1/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /cygdrive/c/Users/drathier/.CLion2016.1/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.5.1/Modules/FindOpenCL.cmake:128 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package)
```

CMakeOutput.log: http://pastebin.com/EgGyRk9H

Comment: Check the CMakeError.log for reasons of OpenCL_LIBRARY not found.

Comment: Where is CMakeError.log? I only see CMakeOutput.log. @usr1234567

Comment: Where you have OpenCL library installed? Which paths to library file (named `OpenCL` with possible prefix and extension). Which path to header file `cl.h`?

Answer (score 3):

In cases where the FindOpenCL CMake Module used by `find_package` fails to find you OpenCL installation, you can override it with the following arguments to CMake

```
-DOpenCL_FOUND=True -DOpenCL_LIBRARY=<PUT_LIBRARY_PATH_HERE>
```

The include path can also be manually set via, `OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR`, see the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindOpenCL.html).

---

The `FindOpenCL` module (see [source](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/c3ef56795102516c2d5c86b5d90808e854cda514/Modules/FindOpenCL.cmake), might look different in your version) checks a number of things to identify some OpenCL SDKs, for instance typical environment variables exported by OpenCL installations:

```
    ENV "PROGRAMFILES(X86)"
    ENV AMDAPPSDKROOT
    ENV INTELOCLSDKROOT
    ENV CUDA_PATH
    ENV NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT
    ENV ATISTREAMSDKROOT
    ENV OCL_ROOT
```

You could check if at least on of these is exported with the correct path, and if not set it yourself, to avoid the manual override described above. Your `CMakeLists.txt` indicates that `CUDA_PATH` should be set, so maybe check that value first. A Further path to debugging could be adding some output to the FindOpenCL module.

Hope that helps & good luck.